# How to get individual data from multiple different <p> elements inside a div

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract individual data from a div that contains multiple paragraph elements.

The HTML:

```
<div class="details" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <p class="details-organisation">
    <span itemprop="name">Test1</span>
  </p>

  <p class="details-block">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <span itemprop="name">
        John Doe
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>


  <p class="details-block">
    <span itemprop="telephone">
      +44(0)123456789
    </span>
  </p>


  <p class="details-block">
    <span itemprop="email">
      <a href="mailto:test@test123.com" data-event-category="Email a supplier" data-event-label="Test">test@test123.com</a>
    </span>
  </p>


</div>
```

For example, i'm trying to pull the 'Test1' text from 'details-organisation'.

My code:

```
    WebElement contactDetails = driver.findElement(By.className("details-organisation"));
    System.out.println(contactDetails.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText());
```

Running this prints out an empty line though.

Comment: Try `contactDetails.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getAttribute("innerHTML")`

Answer (score 0):

when you have extracted a web-element by

```
WebElement contactDetails = driver.findElement(By.className("details-organisation"));
// contactDetails has a valid and an identifiable Web Element
```

you can simply print the text using

```
System.out.println(contactDetails.getText());
```

and even after this you do not get an output, there is probably an issue with the identification of the tag that contains the text, as it not the **paragraph** tag that contains the text, but the **span** tag that does.

You can change the Web Element line as

```
WebElement contactDetails = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'details-organisation']/span/span"));
```

and then proceed to get the text as mentioned earlier.